# FtpWebRequest could not found in Portable Class Library

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to upload a file on ftp web server. I could not found **FtpWebRequest** class in windows phone so, I am trying it by adding new project of Portable Class Library. I have added following code

```
 public void GetDataUsingDataContract(byte[] fileByte)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("uname", "pass");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
       // StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
        byte[] fileContents = fileByte;//Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        //sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
    }
```

But there is also a same issue i.e. I could not found **FtpWebResponse** class. Is it supported in portable class library?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have the answer, the FTPWebRequest / FTPWebResponse are not available in the portable subset of .NET.

This subset is composed of APIs that you can find on all frameworks (Silverlight, XBox, Windows Phone 7/8, .Net x.y etc ...)

If you cannot find an api within a native framework (for instance Windows Phone) you will not find it in the portable library subset.

If you want to use ftp on windows phone, I guess you will have to find a 3rd party api like OpenNETCF FTP that was built for the compact framework.

https://ftp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have considered [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/), but the implementation you are looking for is available at [System.Net.FtpWebRequest](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.FtpWebRequest/).